# YII2 : kartik Select2

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

i have worked on project in advanced yii2 , it works fine in localhost but after i upload it there is a message appear that says :

> Class 'kartik\select2\select2' not found

the weird thing is : select2 works fine in localhost and i upload all the files

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code throwing the error. You're probably missing the use statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution could be:

```php
use kartik\select2\Select2;
```

Maybe you are using Windows on localhost and Linux on the remote server.

Comment: *Maybe* does not belong in an answer. First make it clear what the problem is by the way that you ask OP in the comment section. And only afterwards when you completely understand the problem and have a working solution for that specific issue (so no guessing included) you shell post that as an answer. Otherwise dont post an answer, rather can you suggest something in the comments.

Comment: Let the asker decide if this is the solution that works for him. I have come across the same issue and fixed through above solution, so i hope it helps the asker as well. Or if not him that it can be the solution for future users coming to stackoverflow.

Comment: *May be, you are using windows on localhost and linux on remote server.* - but you are not sure **if** OP's situation is the same as yours, so you are guessing and that is **not** part of an answer! Clear all guessing and missunderstanding in the comments and only **afterwards** post an answer. Otherwise there will occur a mess of several answers, so the question looses quality, same goes with StackOverflow. And thats what comments are for. *Or if not him that it can be the solution for future users coming to stackoverflow.* - but an answer shell only solves **this** issue and not *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you didn't something like "download to localhost kartik select2, then just copy&paste `/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2` to server. I hope. Because you shouldn't do like that.

Add this line to require section in project-directory/composer.json file

```
"kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev"
```

Then run in project directory command:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to a command line interface in your server to run the composer update command, you need to upload the folder "vendor/composer/" and the "vendor/autoload.php" file to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

When moving your code to production, you have to install all libraries used by composer with

```
composer install
```

or

```
php composer.phar install
```

Then the same versions of libraries get installed as on your dev site where you tested the application.

This is the reason why in .gitignore the file composer.lock is NOT included: Just to ensure the same lib versions on dev and prod sites.